Nest Interceptor brokes Azure Service Bus Integration
Context
In my project, I have a gateway REST application and several microservices that communicate via Azure Service Bus. I also use interceptors to handle some cross-cutting concerns in my services. However, I am facing an issue where the controllers in my microservices do not work when an interceptor is attached. When I comment out the interceptor, the controllers function as expected.
Issue
Whenever I send a message to a service from the gateway, the controller doesn't work if an interceptor is attached. When I comment out the interceptor from the service, the controller works as expected. I have already simplified the interceptor to the bare minimum and ensured that ClientProxyService is correctly injected.
Example response when interceptor disabled
RESULT{"maskedGsm":"53******45"}
Example response when interceptor disabled
RESULT{"source":{"source":{}}}
Detailed Description
Here is a brief overview of my setup:
Interceptor Code:
@Injectable()
export class AnalyticInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly client: ClientProxyService) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const eventName = context.getHandler().name;

    if (eventName === 'validate') {
      return next.handle();
    }

    const message = context.switchToRpc().getData();
    const sicil = message.id;
    delete message.sicil;

    return next.handle().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        const payload: IncomingEventPayload = {
          eventName: eventName,
          data: data,
          event_date: new Date(),
          sicil: sicil,
        };
        this.client.emitEvent('auth-event', payload);
        return data;
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        const payload: IncomingEventErrorPayload = {
          eventName: eventName,
          err: err,
          err_date: new Date(),
          sicil: sicil,
        };
        this.client.emitEvent('auth-error', payload);
        throw err;
      })
    );
  }
}

interface IncomingEventPayload {
  eventName: string;
  data: any;
  event_date: Date;
  sicil: number;
}

interface IncomingEventErrorPayload {
  eventName: string;
  err: RpcException;
  err_date: Date;
  sicil: number;
}


Custom Transport Strategy Code
export class AzureServiceBusClient extends Server implements CustomTransportStrategy {
  private serviceBusClient: ServiceBusClient;
  private queueSender: ServiceBusSender;
  private queueReceiver: ServiceBusReceiver;

  constructor(private readonly queueName: string) {
    super();
    this.serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient('Endpoint=sb://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<KeyName>;SharedAccessKey=<AccessKey>');
    this.queueSender = this.serviceBusClient.createSender(this.queueName);
    this.queueReceiver = this.serviceBusClient.createReceiver(this.queueName);
  }

  async connect() {}

  async close() {
    await this.queueReceiver.close();
    await this.queueSender.close();
  }

  async dispatchEvent(packet: ReadPacket<any>): Promise<any> {
    await this.queueSender.sendMessages({
      body: packet.data,
      sessionId: packet.pattern,
    });
  }

  publish(packet: ReadPacket<any>, callback: (packet: WritePacket<any>) => void): () => void {
    const subscription = this.queueReceiver.subscribe({
      processMessage: async (message: any) => {
        if (message.body.pattern === packet.pattern) {
          callback({ response: message.body.result });
        }
      },
      processError: async (args) => {
        console.error('Error receiving message', args);
      },
    });

    this.dispatchEvent(packet);

    return () => {
      subscription.close();
    };
  }

  listen(callback: () => void) {
    this.queueReceiver.subscribe({
      processMessage: async (brokeredMessage) => {
        const handler = this.getHandlerByPattern(brokeredMessage.sessionId);
        if (!handler) {
          console.error(`No handlers for pattern ${brokeredMessage.subject}`);
          return;
        } else {
          const result = await handler(this.deserialize(brokeredMessage).data);
          await this.queueSender.sendMessages({
            body: result,
            sessionId: brokeredMessage.sessionId,
          });
        }
      },
      processError: async (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
    callback();
  }

  private deserialize(message: any): any {
    return {
      pattern: message.subject,
      data: message.body,
    };
  }
}

Example Controller
@Controller()
@UseInterceptors(AnalyticInterceptor) // this broken my transport strategy 
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @MessagePattern('login')
  async login(@Payload() loginDTO: LoginDTO): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.login(loginDTO);
  }

  @MessagePattern('getOtp')
  async getOtp(@Payload() getOtpDto: GetOtpDTO): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.getOtp(getOtpDto);
  }

  @MessagePattern('loginWithGsm')
  async loginWithGsm(@Payload() loginWithGsmDto: LoginViaGsmDTO): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.loginWithGsm(loginWithGsmDto);
  }

  @MessagePattern('checkOtp')
  async checkOTP(@Payload() checkOtpDTO: CheckOtpDTO): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.checkOtp(checkOtpDTO);
  }

  @MessagePattern('refresh')
  async refresh(@Payload() refreshDto: RefreshDTO): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.refresh(refreshDto);
  }

  @MessagePattern('validate')
  async validate(@Payload() validateTokenDto: ValidateTokenDto): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.validate(validateTokenDto);
  }

  @MessagePattern('logout')
  async logout(@Payload() logoutDto: LogoutDTO): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.logout(logoutDto);
  }
}

